# convert json response to javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting json response from my webserver by $.getJSON .  This is the response :

```
[{"id":"1","latitude":"28.63","longitude":"77.21","price":"0"},{"id":"2","latitude":"28.71","longitude":"77.19","price":"100"}]
```

And this is my javascript code to convert this response to arrays :

```
var i = 0;
var vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val();
$.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){
    var lat = [];
    var lon = [];
    var price = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        lat.push(value.latitude);
        lon.push(value.longitude);
        price.push(value.price);
        i++;
    });
});
console.log(i);
```

But when I see the value of i in console it doesn't changes . it's still 0. It means nothing is happening inside `$.each()` . I'm totally new to javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: because it is a asynchronous request

Comment: Your code works just fine in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tBUnz/

Comment: @ArunPJohny his code is inside a callback of `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum no it is not .. I've edited the question with formatted code

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the variable `i` is incremented inside the async callback

Comment: but why `i` is zero in the console ?

Comment: @omerjerk Because the AJAX hasn't returned yet. I'm mistaken and missed your issue. See the Post ArunPJohny linked to.

Comment: @omerjerk answer upated have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var i = 0;
var vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val();
$.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){
    var lat = [];
    var lon = [];
    var price = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $.each(item, function(key, value){
            lat.push(value.latitude);
            lon.push(value.longitude);
            price.push(value.price);
            i++;
        });
    });
    console.log(i);
});
```

Your main problem was that because AJAX is A(synchronous)J(avascript)A(nd)X(ML), notice `asynchronous`, you console.log(i) was being fired before the request was finished. The other problem I noticed was that you were trying to only loop though an object. While your JSON starts with an array which also have to be looped though.

Just a suggestion. Native loops are pretty easy and function faster. I suggestion not using `$.each`:

```
var i = 0;
var vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val();
$.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){
    var lat = [];
    var lon = [];
    var price = [];
    for (var i = 0, item = data[i]; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in item) {
            var value = key[item];
            lat.push(value.latitude);
            lon.push(value.longitude);
            price.push(value.price);
            i++;
        };
    };
    console.log(i);
});
```

Now, I realize that jQuery was made to make your job easier. But I think it is just causing developers to become lazy. I think jQuery is amazing. But i've stopped using `$.each` once I realized that native loops are easy c:

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, my bad. But the `-1` wasn't necessary.

Comment: A -1 does not indicate me not liking you or anything personal. All it does is indicate that I found something wrong with your answer and wanted you to correct it.  In the original version it was similar to OP's code, now that you moved the log to inside the callback it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var i = 0;
var vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val();
var jsonData;
$.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){

    jsonData = data;
});
var lat = [];
    var lon = [];
    var price = [];
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
        lat.push(value.latitude);
        lon.push(value.longitude);
        price.push(value.price);
        i++;
    });
console.log(i);
```

Comment: He wanted to log the last value of `i`, not the value on every iteration.

Comment: hey says "value of i in console it doesn't changes . it's still 0. It means nothing is happening inside $.each()" the above modification will show that the value of i changing

Comment: Read his code carefully. His console.log is _outside_ the getJSON which means deferred execution will stop it from incrementing before the AJAX returns.

Answer (score 0):

Using asynchronous functions in javascript can sometimes be confusing, here is why

**EXAMPLE**:

```
var result = 'pending';
$.ajax({
  url: 'something.php',
  success: function() {
    result = 'success';
  }
});
```

> Now if we want to use result here we would not get a good result

`console.log(result); // 'pending'`

So instead I think you're better off calling 'function' on that one like this

```
var makeArray = function( data ) {
    var i = 0,
        vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val(),
        lat = [], lon = [], price = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        lat.push(value.latitude);
        lon.push(value.longitude);
        price.push(value.price);
        i++;
    });
    console.log(i);
}; 

$.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){
    makeArray( data );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the index:

```
var data = [{"id":"1","latitude":"28.63","longitude":"77.21","price":"0"},
            {"id":"2","latitude":"28.71","longitude":"77.19","price":"100"},
            {"id":"2","latitude":"28.71","longitude":"77.19","price":"100"}];
var i;
var lat = [];
var lon = [];
var price = [];

$.each(data, function(index, value){
    lat.push(value.latitude);
    lon.push(value.longitude);
    price.push(value.price);
    i = index;
});

console.log(i);
```

Check out this fiddle, I think it should be doing what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/vmy3b/3/